# log4net doesn't output anything

Tags: c#, log4net

Here is my class:

```
internal class App : IDisposable
{
   private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(App));

   internal void Start()
   {
            _log.Info("info");
            _log.Debug("debug");
            _log.Warn("warn");
            _log.Error("error");
            _log.Fatal("fatal");
            Console.WriteLine("test");
   }

   // ...
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void Main()
{
   var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
   XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new Hierarchy(), new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir, "log4net.xml")));

   // ...
}
```

.csproj entry:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="../*.env" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
    <None Include="../log4net.xml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

log4net.xml:

```
<log4net xmlns="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd">
  <appender name="console-default" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console-default"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

`_log` object I get:
[image: log object debug]

I also tried to add

```
using log4net.Config;
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

in `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`

Program output:
[image: app output]

The same thing is if i replace appender with `FileAppender` it's just creating an empty file

`log4net.xml` file is copied each build into build directory near executable file
`log4net` version 2.0.8
config file is read correctly. If I change something it will throw error on initialization
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an `ILoggerRepository` instance instead of a `Hierarchy` to the `XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch`.

---

```
var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
ILoggerRepository repository = log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(repository, new FileInfo(Path.Combine(dir, "log4net.config")));
```

---

There is no reason to have an `xml namespace` declaration on the configuration; use

```
<log4net>
```

instead of

```
<log4net mlns="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd">
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. Xml namespace doesn't affect configuration. I've added this only for autocompletion